# WinError 5:Access denied PyTesseract

Tags: python, windows, error-handling, ocr, python-tesseract

I know this question has already been answered on this site, however, none of the solutions I looke up the internet seemed to work. Here's what I tried:

- Giving all permissions to my python file
- Changing PATH variable to point to my tesseract folder
- Running IDLE as administrator and then executing the file from there

This error is quite bothering me now and I can't advance any further because of it.

Here's my code if that's going to help:

```
import pytesseract
import sys
import argparse
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
from subprocess import check_output
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR'
c=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('img.png'))
print(c)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\bot.py", line 12, in <module>
    c=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('captcha.png'))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
config=config)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accès refusé
```

Comment: Can someone take a look at this and help me with this problem?

Comment: can you supply the full Traceback you got ?

Comment: @Fruch I don't have them on me because I reinstalled Python in an other location. The reason I did this was because, after investigating the Traceback and my folders, I found that the python folder was inside a protected folder 'Hp', so I decided to reinstall it in another location (C Disk) in hope to solving this problem.

Comment: Try using cmd and run it as administrator, then changing to the directory where the png file is.

Comment: @Marichyasana Tried it already, doesn't work.

Comment: How about if you log in to the administrator account? There are some differences from using administrator from a user account.

Comment: @Marichyasana All I have is one account.

Comment: `c=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(os.getcwd()+'\\'+'captcha.png'))` if image in same directory with script !

Answer (score 26):

I encountered same problem, and I fixed it as 0xc0de said, change the below line:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r"C:\MyApps\Tesseract-ocr\"
```

to:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd="C:\\MyApps\\Tesseract-ocr\\tesseract.exe"
```

Comment: This worked for me (indipendently from raw vs not raw string and double \\)

Answer (score 20):

I suspect a few things, not sure about any though.

First and the most obvious, the path to Tesseract is not complete. It should be something like:

```
tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'
```

I believe your path points to a directory/folder and not an executable, though only you can confirm that. Let me know if this is incorrect, I see something else too that doesn't seem right at first, but needs more investigation.

Comment: If this worked, and if your installation if fresh & default, removing this line from your code altogether should work too.

Comment: when I include the executable it spawns a winerror 2 error

Comment: @OussamaBoussif you really need to give more details of that. Those 3 words will not lead you to any solution.

Answer (score 5):

Use this to read the tesseract path and also make sure that you have installed the Tesseract- OCR

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\\Program Files (x86)\\\Tesseract-OCR\\\tesseract.exe'
```

using always double \\ instead of a single "\"

Comment: why do we need to include the `tesseract.exe`?

Comment: @DonCarleone just in case that someone has the same question. Pythesseract is a python wrapper for google's Thesseract so you must have both.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install tesseract separately. I am providing the link from where you should install

https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

tesseract-ocr-w32-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20201127.exe (32 bit) and
tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20201127.exe (64 bit) resp.

choose here according to your system config. most of us have 64 bit. so choose that.

Install the file very carefully. I Would suggest doing it in a separate drive other than c.
take the path where you have install the tesseract.exe file. and paste it at pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd

look the code...

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'E:/OCR/tesseract_install/tesseract.exe'
img = cv2.imread('E:/OCR/example1.png')
# to see the image below codes are there
cv2.imshow('sampleimage',img)
#enter any key to destroy the image window opened due to previous line code
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#convert image to text using tesseract
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issues pretty consistent, and I fix it without any access change.
The trick is:

1: You need to install tesseract and remember where is path to tesseract.exe file.

2: Then install pytesseract on exect environment you going to use it using `pip install pytesseract`

3: Do not add any Path to your System Env variables, it will mess up with everything.

4: CLEARLY define path to image file, or even better if image will be in closest/the same directory where is your python code.

```
 from PIL import Image     
 import pytesseract   
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:/Users/your_name/AppData/Local/Programs/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract' 
        
 #this path to image      
path = r'C:\Users\irina_max\Documents\Python_Scripts\Invoice 1.jpg'  
image= Image.open(path) 
image
```

Answer (score -1):

Install the tesseract exe in a directory inside your project. I did the above and it worked fine, without giving Win 5 error.